# Head CT Scan Risks

Tags: pediatrics, risks, radiation, ct-scans

Please go through the attached image and confirm if the repeated head CT scan is too much for a 6 yr old boy. Will there be any long term side effects?

I would appreciate a quick response to my question.

[image: CT Scan Parameters]

Comment: This still fits much better to health.se, as anongoodnurse indicated. I will move the question there, please check there if further adaptations are needed.

Comment: It is impossible to predict (yes, literally **impossible**) how much radiation would be damaging for a particular individual. The only question you should be asking yourself (I'm assuming you're the child's parent) is *`"Is the potential risk worth it?"`* Did the patient just fall off the swings, or have they had severe undiagnosed headaches for weeks/months? Are the physicians looking for remnants of cancer after surgery/medical therapy? Everything is completely dependent on context. Questions regarding personal medical advice are off-topic here. Talk to the attending physician instead.